# Jquery AJAX Effects

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader, effect

I am trying to load page with ajax and its working fine without issue but I want to add fadeIn fadeOut effect and loader gif animation.

Can anyone please help me to do that. I am using below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // load index page when the page loads
    $("#main").load("content.php");

    $("#home").click(function(){
    // load home page on click
        $("#main").load("content.php");
    });
    $("#mediakit").click(function(){
    // load about page on click
        $("#main").load("mm-media-kit.php");
    });
});
```

I am not experienced with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ and http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ to show and hide a loading image in this case. Like this

I am assuming you have a loading image div with id `loading` somewhere in your page which is initially hidden. Then you can show loading image using this two function above like this

```
//show the loader at the start of ajax request
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
   $(this).show();
 });
//hide the loader when ajax request Completes
$("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

Comment: This code works great to show and hide loader Thanks I up voated :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='main'></div>
<div id='mainloading'><img src='loading.gif'></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#main").fadeOut().load("content.php", function() {
    $(this).fadeIn();
    $('#mainloading').hide();
});
```

Comment: Did you set loading image path correctly in place of `loading.gif` in html part?

Comment: My mistake. Its working completely fine without any problem. Thanks a lot. Only one thing just to get more perfection. Its give some kind of jerk while loading instead of fadein any reason?

Comment: hmmm. No idea. Please try something like `$(this).fadeIn('slow');`, or need to do some more research.

Comment: I did that but not working its loading page first and fadeing out and again fading in. Something is wrong I believe.

Comment: I got the reason but not the solution. The reason is as it loads the page its loading and fading out as defined .fadeOut().load() than in child function defined fadeIn() so its fading in again. So something need to swap or removed I tried but not able to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **animate** on the opacity CSS property to fade in/out as needed.  (Set the opacity to zero before load, then animate back to 1 on your load callback.)

```
$("#main").css('opacity', 0).load("mm-media-kit.php", function() {
    $("#main").animate({ opacity: 1}, 'slow');
});
```

The functions **fadeIn** / **fadeOut** are basically shorthand for the above, but I suppose you don't really want to fade out in this scenario.